# Can I vent room air to the outside?

Tags: hvac, vent, ventilation, cooling

The building interior gets hot during the day and stays hot during the evening when it is much cooler outside. It would be a really great option to simply vent the hot air outside instead of having to turn the air-conditioner on.

I'm looking for a more structural and long-term solution than just opening a window and propping a fan right next to it, something like a decent-sized exhaust vent to the outside with a switch-activated fan attached would be a good solution.

Is this something that has already been done and are there existing products or plans that can be referenced?

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer to my own question, this seems like a great solution:

http://energy.gov/energysaver/cooling-whole-house-fan